# WebDeploy to Azure oca failing: Insufficient acces to site folder

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, asp.net-core, webdeploy

I am using WebDeploy (msdeploy.exe) to deploy an ASP.NET Core app to an Azure App Service instance.

This works fine most of the time, but sometimes the deployment fails with the error message: Unable to perform the operation ("Create File")  for the specified directory. (...) ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.

I believe this is some file locking issue, because the only way out of this is to log into Azure Portal and stop the App Service, and then redeploy. After this, deployment is fine for a while, until the same happens again.

Having spent some time setting up automatic deployment, this hickup is very annoying.

Is there any way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing, as i understand, with the Azure - the error is a bit common.
As for Azure Web Apps, there are two options:

1) Stop your site and deploy.

2) If the first one is not OK, then use Kudu Console, find your file (for example, d:\home...\something.blocked) and rename the file. After that, the problem should be away

---

If that is the helpful answer, please mark it as a helpful or mark it as the answer. Thanks!